# Можно ли увеличить лимит конструктора JAVA?

Tags: java

Код очень объемный, из-за чего столкнулся с лимитом:
     The code of constructor Window(String) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit.
Можно ли как-то увеличить этот лимит, если нет, то что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Очевидно же - сокращать код.

Comment: нечего сокращать

Comment: Не верю. В 64 кб всегда найдется что сократить, упростить или вынести в другой класс.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Вынесите что-то в статические методы этого класса. Там... например, генерацию некоторых полей.

Comment: Честно говоря, я даже не представляю себе 64-х килобайтный конструктор) вынесите что-то в приватные методы класса и вызывайте их из конструктора. Никаких проблем.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет, этот лимит увеличить нельзя. Это ограничение виртуальной машины, [закреплённое в спецификации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11).

Размеры методов надо сокращать. Особенно конструкторов. И для этого всегда есть возможность. Вот что по этому поводу пишет авторитетный Роберт Мартин в своём знаменитом труде "Чистый код":

> Первое правило: функции должны быть компактными. Второе правило:
>   функции должны быть еще компактнее. Я не могу научно обосновать свое
>   утверждение. Не ждите от меня ссылок на исследования, доказывающие,
>   что очень маленькие функции лучше больших. Я могу всего лишь сказать,
>   что я почти четыре десятилетия писал функции всевозможных размеров.
>   Мне доводилось создавать кошмарных монстров в 3000 строк. Я написал
>   бесчисленное множество функций длиной от 100 до 300 строк. И я писал
>   функции от 20 до 30 строк. Мой практический опыт научил меня (ценой
>   многих проб и ошибок), что функции должны быть очень маленькими. В
>   80-е годы считалось, что функция должна занимать не более одного
>   экрана. Конечно, тогда экраны VT100 состояли из 24 строк и 80
>   столбцов, а редакторы использовали 4 строки для административных
>   целей. В наши дни с мелким шрифтом на хорошем большом мониторе можно
>   разместить 150 символов в строке и 100 и более строк на экране. Однако
>   строки не должны состоять из 150 символов, а функции — из 100 строк.
>   Желательно, чтобы длина функции не превышала **20 строк**.